# $X_i + X_i^2$ where $X_i \sim$ normal; what is the distribution?

Tags: normal-distribution, chi-squared-distribution, distribution-identification

$X_i + X_i^2$ where $X_i \sim$ normal. Does this sum have any particular distribution?

Comment: Observe $X_i + X_i^2 = (X_i+1/2)^2 - 1/4$ and note that $X_i+1/2$ also has a Normal distribution.

Comment: The result may be a [scaled and shifted noncentral chi-square distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noncentral_chi-squared_distribution).

Comment: `z <- rnorm(10000); hist(z+z^2,freq=FALSE,breaks=100,col="gray"); curve(dchisq(x+1/4,df=1,ncp=1/2),add=TRUE,col=2)`

Answer (score 3):

By using high-school algebra we have $X_i + X_i^2 = (X_i+1/2)^2 - 1/4$ and $X_i+1/2$ also has a normal distribution, in general non-centered. So its square will be a scaled (since variance of $X_i$ might not be 1) non-central [chi-square distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noncentral_chi-squared_distribution) but because of the other term $- 1/4$ it will be a shifted version of such.

A simulated example:

[image: simulated histogram with overlaid density]

(See the comments)